# How to check visibility of item in FlatList at different visibility percentages?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-native

I am trying to perform an action on a given item inside of React Native `FlatList` when it becomes visible in 2 different scenarios:

1. When the item is 10% visible (perform fade/scale animation)
2. When the items is 100% visible (start playing video/audio when on screen)

From the RN documentation, it states that is it not possible to change the `viewabilityConfig` on demand.

How can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just noticed that `FlatList` takes a prop called `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` whose format is not fully documented at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#viewabilityconfigcallbackpairs

Basically what this does is that it will take an array of objects with key/value pairs for `viewabilityConfig` and `onViewableItemsChanged`. This will allow you to define any handlers for each different viewability configurations.

For example:

```js
<FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id }
    refreshing={false}
    onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
    viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={this.viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs}
/>
```

Where `this.viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` would equal:

```js
this.viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = [{
    viewabilityConfig: {
      minimumViewTime: 500,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100
    },
    onViewableItemsChanged: this.handleItemsInViewPort
  },
  {
    viewabilityConfig: {
      minimumViewTime: 150,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 10
    },
    onViewableItemsChanged: this.handleItemsPartiallyVisible
  }
];
```

Comment: I wrote a article about the viewability event of FlatList.  https://suelan.github.io/2020/01/21/onViewableItemsChanged/. It is helpful to understand what is going on behind these API.

Comment: Works with class component but I cant get this to work in a functional component, can anyone please provide some code for FC? edit: nevermind got it working using  const pairs = useRef(viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs);

Answer (score 1):

So here is the example with Functional Components,

```
<FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id }
    refreshing={false}
    onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
    viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
/>
```

Where `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` would equal:

```
  const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = React.useRef([{
    viewabilityConfig: {
      minimumViewTime: 500,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100,
    },
    onViewableItemsChanged: onViewCallBack
  },
  {
    viewabilityConfig: {
      minimumViewTime: 150,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 10
    },
    onViewableItemsChanged: onViewCallBackPartially
  }
]);
```

Where `onViewCallBack` `onViewCallBackPartially` and would equal:

```
  const onViewCallBackPartially = React.useCallback(({ viewableItems }: any) => {
    console.log('onViewCallBackPartially', viewableItems);
  }, []);

  const onViewCallBack = React.useCallback(({ viewableItems }: any) => {
    console.log('onViewCallBack', viewableItems);
  }, []);
```